# Docx4J.Bind doesn't work with pictures?

Tags: java, image, docx4j

I am using these two methods to change the contents of content controls.

```
Docx4J.bind
( 
    lc_docxPackage,
    new ByteArrayInputStream( ic_data ), 
    ai_flags
);
Docx4J.save( lc_docxPackage, ac_os );
```

Howewer when trying to change a picture, created document contains only red cross picture saying: "Picture cannot be shown", while text fields are changed properly. Manually mapping those pictures works.

Using OpenDoPe authoring tool I can see that the changed content controls do not contain any XPath.

Is this feature not supported and should I use something else to change contents of pictures?

Comment: Should work fine.  Can you upload your docx somewhere so we can inspect it?

Comment: Hello, @Jason. I am sorry I bothered You. It works well right now. I do not know for sure what caused this problem, but I presume it was caused by different namespaces in original and injected custom XMLs. On a side note, Docx4J.toPDF does not support different fonts, or is it supported  just in paid version?

Comment: actually, toPDF does support other fonts using either method (via XSL FO, or the commercial product)

Comment: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docs/OpenDoPE_Images.docx may be of interest